# window.focus() not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser, dom-events

Just wondering if Google Chrome is going to support `window.focus()` at some point. When I mean support, I mean have it work. The call to it doesn't fail, it just doesn't do anything. All other major browsers do not have this problem: FireFox, IE6-IE8 and Safari.

I have a client-side class for managing browser windows. When I first create a window the window comes into focus, but subsequent attempts to bring focus to the window do not work.

From what I can tell, this appears to be a security feature to avoid annoying pop-ups and it does not appear to be a WebKit issue as it works in Safari.

I know one idea someone brought forward was to close the window then reopen it, but this is a horrible solution. Googling shows that I do not appear to be the only person frustrated with this.

And just to be 100% clear, I mean new windows, not tabs (tabs cannot be focused from what I've read) and all the windows being opened are in the same domain.

Any ideas, workarounds aside from the bad one I mention above?

There is a bug logged on the Chromium project about this, check it out [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1383&can=1&q=window.focus%20type%3aBug&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner). Thanks for posting that [Rich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16511/rich-bradshaw).

```
MyCompany = { UI: {} }; // Put this here if you want to test the code. I create these namespaces elsewhere in code.

MyCompany.UI.Window = new function() {
    // Private fields
    var that = this;
    var windowHandles = {};

    // Public Members
    this.windowExists = function(windowTarget) {
        return windowTarget && windowHandles[windowTarget] && !windowHandles[windowTarget].closed;
    }

    this.open = function(url, windowTarget, windowProperties) {
        // See if we have a window handle and if it's closed or not.
        if (that.windowExists(windowTarget)) {

            // We still have our window object so let's check if the URLs is the same as the one we're trying to load.
            var currentLocation = windowHandles[windowTarget].location;

            if (
                (
                    /^http(?:s?):/.test(url) && currentLocation.href !== url
                )
                    ||
                (
                    // This check is required because the URL might be the same, but absolute,
                    // e.g. /Default.aspx ... instead of http://localhost/Default.aspx ...
                    !/^http(?:s?):/.test(url) &&
                    (currentLocation.pathname + currentLocation.search + currentLocation.hash) !== url
                )
            ) {
                // Not the same URL, so load the new one.
                windowHandles[windowTarget].location = url;
            }

            // Give focus to the window. This works in IE 6/7/8, FireFox, Safari but not Chrome.
            // Well in Chrome it works the first time, but subsequent focus attempts fail,. I believe this is a security feature in Chrome to avoid annoying popups.
            windowHandles[windowTarget].focus();
        }
        else
        {
            // Need to do this so that tabbed browsers (pretty much all browsers except IE6) actually open a new window
            // as opposed to a tab. By specifying at least one window property, we're guaranteed to have a new window created instead
            // of a tab.
            windowProperties = windowProperties || 'menubar=yes,location=yes,width=700, height=400, scrollbars=yes, resizable= yes';
            windowTarget = windowTarget || "_blank";

            // Create a new window.
            var windowHandle = windowProperties ? window.open(url, windowTarget, windowProperties) : window.open(url, windowTarget);

            if (null === windowHandle) {
                alert("You have a popup blocker enabled. Please allow popups for " + location.protocol + "//" + location.host);
            }
            else {
                if ("_blank" !== windowTarget) {
                    // Store the window handle for reuse if a handle was specified.
                    windowHandles[windowTarget] = windowHandle;
                    windowHandles[windowTarget].focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having this problem for IE 8-9.Any ideas?

Comment: 10 years later and the issue is still there, none of the workarrounds work for me when trying to focus a sibling window :-(

Answer (score 12):

I've been struggling with this issue. I wanted a reference to another window, so I was issuing a:

```
otherWinRef = window.open("","OtherWindow");
```

However when I issue this command, the browser will switch focus to the OtherWindow. I thought this could be addressed by doing this:

```
otherWinRef = window.open("","OtherWindow");
window.focus();
```

but the window.focus() has no effect. I tried:

```
otherWinRef = window.open("","OtherWindow");
setTimeout(window.focus,0);
```

But the window.focus() call still had no effect.

I resolve the issue by adding the following code to the OtherWindow's source.

```
function Bounce(w) {

        window.blur();
        w.focus();
}
```

Then I changed the code in the main window to:

```
otherWinRef = window.open("","OtherWindow");
otherWinRef.Bounce(window);
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be working now (October 2021)

Answer (score 9):

Still the same in version 14.0.835.202 m on Windows 7; found another workaround, not more elegant but at least will avoid losing data on the page: show an alert in the window you want to focus.

Comment: In the case of pop-unders, this will only return focus until the alert is closed.

Answer (score 8):

UPDATE: This solution appears to no longer work in Chrome.

Unbelievably, the solution is quite simple. I've been trying to figure this issue out for at least a week. All you need to do is blur the window then give it focus. I had tried this previously and it didn't work.

```
windowHandle.blur();
windowHandle.focus();
```

So I ended up trying this instead:

```
windowHandle.blur();
setTimeout(windowHandle.focus, 0);
```

and that seems to work.

I've updated my code here:

```
MyCompany = { UI: {} }; // Put this here if you want to test the code. I create these namespaces elsewhere in code.

MyCompany.UI.Window = new function() {       
    // Private fields
    var that = this;
    var windowHandles = {};
    var isChrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

    // Public Members
    this.focus = function(windowHandle) {
        if (!windowHandle) {
            throw new Exception("Window handle can not be null.");
        }

        if (isChrome) {
            windowHandle.blur();
            setTimeout(windowHandle.focus, 0);                    
        }
        else {
            windowHandle.focus();
        }    
    }

    this.windowExists = function(windowTarget) {
        return windowTarget && windowHandles[windowTarget] && !windowHandles[windowTarget].closed;
    }

    this.open = function(url, windowTarget, windowProperties) {
        // See if we have a window handle and if it's closed or not.
        if (that.windowExists(windowTarget)) {

            // We still have our window object so let's check if the URLs is the same as the one we're trying to load.
            var currentLocation = windowHandles[windowTarget].location;

            if (
                (
                    /^http(?:s?):/.test(url) && currentLocation.href !== url
                )
                    ||
                (
                    // This check is required because the URL might be the same, but absolute,
                    // e.g. /Default.aspx ... instead of http://localhost/Default.aspx ...
                    !/^http(?:s?):/.test(url) &&
                    (currentLocation.pathname + currentLocation.search + currentLocation.hash) !== url
                )
            ) {
                // Not the same URL, so load the new one.
                windowHandles[windowTarget].location = url;
            }

            // Give focus to the window. This works in IE 6/7/8, FireFox, Safari but not Chrome.
            // Well in Chrome it works the first time, but subsequent focus attempts fail,. I believe this is a security feature in Chrome to avoid annoying popups.
            that.focus(windowHandles[windowTarget]);
        }
        else {
            // Need to do this so that tabbed browsers (pretty much all browsers except IE6) actually open a new window
            // as opposed to a tab. By specifying at least one window property, we're guaranteed to have a new window created instead
            // of a tab.
            //windowProperties = windowProperties || 'menubar=yes,location=yes,width=700, height=400, scrollbars=yes, resizable= yes';
            windowProperties = windowProperties || 'menubar=yes,location=yes,width=' + (screen.availWidth - 15) + ', height=' + (screen.availHeight - 140) + ', scrollbars=yes, resizable= yes';
            windowTarget = windowTarget || "_blank";

            // Create a new window.
            var windowHandle = windowProperties ? window.open(url, windowTarget, windowProperties) : window.open(url, windowTarget);

            if (null === windowHandle || !windowHandle) {
                alert("You have a popup blocker enabled. Please allow popups for " + location.protocol + "//" + location.host);
            }
            else {
                if ("_blank" !== windowTarget) {
                    // Store the window handle for reuse if a handle was specified.
                    windowHandles[windowTarget] = windowHandle;
                    windowHandles[windowTarget].focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same problem but this solution did not work for me. I am using Chrome 5.0.375.125 for Mac OS X (Snow Leopard).
 Can you confirm that it works on both Windows and Mac?

Comment: @Nick - I only tested it on Chrome for Windows.

Comment: if anyone has a work-around for Chrome on Mac I would appreciate it!

Comment: The above solution : 

    windowHandle.blur();  
    setTimeout(windowHandle.focus, 0);

does not seem to work on Chrome 8.0.552.237.
Are there any other workarounds to give focus to a popup window using setTimeout?

Comment: It appears that my workaround no longer works. I'm in Chrome 10.x

Comment: Cool, this works on Chrome 5 for Windows (even w/o `setTimeout`)

Comment: This used to work, but does not anymore in chrome - 21.0.1180.60 m

Comment: Seems chrome developers keep this breaking after reading the solutions here :)

Comment: Version 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit) Mac OSX 10.11.1. Simple blur and focus works for me.

Comment: Not on 47.0.2526.106 m (64-bit) on W8.1

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Chrome 51.0.2704.63 on Windows 7. I'm trying to bring child/popup windows back into focus on a web application. Haven't found any way to do it yet.

Answer (score 4):

The only solution that currently works in Chrome is this code inside new window:

```
$(".closeBtn").click( function(e) 
{
    window.open("",window.opener.name);
    window.close();
});
```

Unfortunately the solution only works under two conditions:

- `window.opener` has to have it's name set on document load (`window.name="WhateverName";`)
- `window.open()` is called on user click

Answer (score 4):

you can `focus` another window by calling `open` with `javascript:;` as `url` parameter:

```
window.open('http://....', 'myWindow');

// focus that window later on...
window.open('javascript:;', 'myWindow');
```

Comment: The issue is not to focus the new window. The issue is that you want to keep focus to the old window when opening the new (new opens in background).

Answer (score 3):

A suggestion from [someone's blog](http://www.razzed.com/2009/03/16/chrome-problems-window-focus-workaround/) is to use this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome/') > 0) {
    if (window.detwin) {
        window.detwin.close();
        window.detwin = null;
    }
}
window.detwin = window.open(URL,  'windowname', '...');
window.detwin.focus();
```

Following [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1383&can=1&q=window.focus%20type:Bug&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner) might be useful.

Comment: @Rich, I mention this in my question. It's a bad solution though. What if the popup has data that you want to save? Killing the window and reopening the url just seems bad.

Comment: @Rich, I also saw the bug you mentioned, but thanks for posting for others to see.

Comment: The above solution : 

    windowHandle.blur();  
    setTimeout(windowHandle.focus, 0);

does not seem to work on Chrome 8.0.552.237.
Are there any other workarounds to give focus to a popup window using setTimeout?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a workaround I was able to use. It may not work for everybody, but it does what I need it to, and it does handle scenarios where your popup has been updated via Ajax after the initial load (ie - it doesn't go back to the server to reload the page).

```js
function refocusWindow() {
  var newName = window.name + '-2'; // you'll want to customize this for your needs
  var options = ''; // again, customize for your situation
  var w = window.open('', newName, options);
  w.document.write(document.getElementById('everything').innerHTML);
  window.close();
}
```

I'm using the new window trick to make it look like I'm just refocusing the page, but I'm actually creating a new window with the exact contents of the old window and then closing the old window.

You'll just need to make sure that you are able to grab everything you need for the new window. I put everything I need in an `#everything` div; you may need to change this for your needs.

Hope this at least helps some of you.

***Note**: inline Javascript seems to execute with this approach, linked Javascript may not. Proceed with caution if this will be a problem for you.*

Comment: Interesting approach! I'm curious how does this affect JS in <script> tags embedded on the page. It's worth noting that this works only for popups opened from the same domain, as cross-origin restrictions would apply. And why don't you just get <html> or <body> with getElementsByTagName instead of having #everything?

Comment: It runs my inline `<script>` tags just fine, I don't have any JS pulled in from other files. The reason I use my `#everything` div is that I have JS that I **don't** want to run when I reopen the page. I realize that's probably not very common, but it's what I needed to do.

Comment: The second part answers exactly what I was asking :) When you refocus the window, no scripts get re-executed, while this approach breaks that assumption. It's not bad, just could be surprising to some, and maybe it needs emphasizing.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer yep, but in my situation, that doesn't matter

Answer (score 3):

`window.focus()` for child windows works fine for me on Chrome v52 on Windows, but ONLY inside a user-initiated event, e.g. a click callback. (This is the same restriction that the pop-up blocker applies to `window.open()` calls.)

Comment: This is the only sensible answer in the whole lot of answers. Would be great if this was documented somewhere as I can't find anything to say this is the case, but that certainly appears to be what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I simply use this line of code here to refocus, it's the best thing that's worked for me so far:

```js
    window.open('', 'NameOfTheOpenedWindow').focus();
```

thanks to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30758862/10706668)

I also made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Foxygaming9978/6gc38f5x/) for testing.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I just found out a quite simple solution.

If you reopen a window that is in a background position, targeting the same window ("_self"), Chrome automatically focus that window.

To regain focus of a window you should use the following code:

```
path = windowHandle.document.URL;
windowHandle.open(path,"_self");
```

Comment: This solution would work if not violating CORS.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.
Removed launching blank window from catch block, instead launching the url directly, which avoids user's confusion when he says blank window.

```
windowHandle = window.open('', 'PrintInvoice', urlOptions);
try {
    windowHandle.document.location.href = url;
} catch (exc) {
    windowHandle.close();
    windowHandle = window.open(url, 'PrintInvoice', urlOptions);
}
windowHandle.focus();
```

Comment: @user9761888 - This is a poor solution as you lose the entire state of the page. If you don't care about state, then this works, but still dirty.

Answer (score 0):

I fought this in Chrome. I wanted a popup window to display when the user clicked a link on the parent screen. Works the first time the popup window is displayed, but once the popup loses focus, javascript can't bring it back to the front again; you must manually click on the window.  Here is what worked for me. This script is the parent window (the one with the links). As you can see, I put it at the end of the HEAD section::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var infoWindow;

  function openLink(url)   {
    infoWindow = window.open("", "infoWindow", "width=880, height=500, top=20, left=20, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes, resizable=yes");
    infoWindow.location.href=url;
    infoWindow.focus();
  }

  function closeWindow()   {
    if (infoWindow)   {
      infoWindow.close();
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black" onFocus="closeWindow()" onLoad="closeWindow()">
```

All links are `<A href="Javascript: openLink('url')">`. If the user does not close the popup window manually, it is closed when the parent window regains focus.  So the popup is destroyed and re-created every time. Seems kinda convoluted, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what everyone wants either, but (in chrome) I noticed that an alert raised from the pop uped page keeps hold on the focus of the popup. So I'm doing this now...

On the pop uped page, have a function loaded in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmBlur() {
        if (confirm("Do you want to close this window?")) {
            window.close();
        }
    }
</script>`
```

And then on the pop uped page:

```
<body onblur="ConfirmBlur()">
```

So this is a variant of closing the popup when the focus is lost. But in my case, the popup is an edit window for data. A window, one doesn't want to close unasked. So now the user gets notified the focus is about to drop and gets a choice if he wants to close the window or not. Again, far from perfect, but it worked for me.

(be gentle)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open('javascript:void(0)', 'myWindow');
```

Comment: Please don't forget to explain / comment your code, and provide relevant documentation [from review]

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions here worked for me. So, I came up with this:

```
$('<form target="_blank" action="'+URL+'" method="post"></form>')
    .appendTo('body').submit();
```

This creates a blank form that is submitted via post to the target URL. By applying `target="_blank"` we mimic calling window.open() with the side effect of maintaining focus on the new window.

Edit: Vanilla JS version that also removes the form element afterwards:

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method', 'post');
f.setAttribute('action', URL);
f.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
f.submit();
f.parentNode.removeChild(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to solve my problem when I used **setTimeout()** and encapsulated the **focus()** inside an anonymous **function**. Here is an example:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   myField.focus();
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

My good friends! Haha! There is only ONE way to focus a window (bring to front) in google chrome automatically. This complicated method took me a long time to find. So please share this method with others!

My problem was I wanted my google chrome extension to open in a new window when I click on it. However, google chrome does not want unknown windows to focus automatically. So It would open the window minimized.

I wanted it to open not minimized, but every piece of code that would do that would also glitch it and break the window. But I found a workaround.

Any peace of code with window.focus will NOT WORK IN CHROME:

```
window.focus   //DOES NOT WORK IN CHROME!!
```

To focus the window, you have to make a button that opens the window and then click that button using javascript.

Button HTML:

```
<button class='open' id='open' onclick='open()'></button>
```

You can make the button invisible in CSS:

```
.open {
ocupacity: 0;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
}
```

This js code is to make sure that it only opens every 2 times, because if the js code opens in a new window, then it counts as opening twice:

```
open = localStorage.getItem('open')
if (open == 1){                            //1 is don't open window
    localStorage.setItem('open',0)    
} else {                                   //0 is open window
    setTimeout(function(){           //Set timeout lets the page load first
        var openbutton = document.getElementById("open");
        openbutton.click()                 // Clicks the button
    }, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('open',1)
}
```

This js code is the function that opens it in a new window, but since it is being opened by a button it will open normally:

```
open() {
    window.close();      //closes the chrome extension popup
    window.open(document.URL, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=653,width=400,scrollbars=no,status=yes');   //opens it in new window
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you pass the same name to window.open(url,name,features) in Chrome more than once, Chrome recognizes that it is already open which is fine, but it won't focus it no matter what you do.

Chrome will however return the handle of the existing window, so you can then close it and reopen it.  At that point focusing will be superfluous.

Here is what worked for me:

```
    var win=window.open(url,name,features);
    win.close();
    var win=window.open(url,name,features);
```

// where url, name and features are variables.

This works fine regardless of whether or not the window is already open.

Note: if you change the window name each time by using the time or a random number or the url itself, the window will open in focus, but you will get a new window every time and they can accumulate.  If you want to keep using the same window to display different urls, just keep using the same window name.

I use this for displaying archived Vendor Invoice pdfs where the url is for each is stored in a table.  If you keep opening one after another, you want to use the same window but have it focus when you access it.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error `chrome.windows.update(windowId, {focused: true})` is working for me.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/windows#method-update