# Open link in new window or focus to it if already open

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link which should open in a new tab, but if the tab is already open, just switch to it. 
I've tried with javascript, wnd = window.open() and than wnd.focus(), that works in Chrome 19, but not in FF 13  or IE 9. 
Here's the code I've written :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loadingTableWnd;
function openOrSwitchToWindow(url){
if(loadingTableWnd == undefined)
loadingTableWnd = window.open(url,'myFrame');
else
loadingTableWnd.focus();
}
</script> 
<a href='javascript:openOrSwitchToWindow("/");' >Loading Table</a>
```

Any idea how can I open or switch to from every browser?

**EDIT**: I need to open the link in a new tab, not a stand-alone window.

Comment: There is a bug that has been filed a while ago, hasn't been fixed yet - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416771

Comment: That bug was submitted in 2008. Here it is in 2016 with Firefox 47 and it still has not been resolved. Can anyone (with some pull) please escalate?

Comment: In 2019 (Firefox 69) the bug was fixed.

Comment: If the url opens in a new window or tab depends on browser settings. To open in a new window instead of a tab I use window [specs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp): `let windowFeatures = 'resizable=yes'; window.open('url', 'whatever', windowFeatures);`. Works in Chrome.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Different browsers behave differently for window.open() and focus().
For this code `window.open('www.sample.com','mywindow').focus()`

- **Chrome 20** opens a new tab, and focuses on subsequent open() calls regardless if focus() is called or not.
- **Firefox 13** opens a new tab, focuses on first open(), does not focus on subsequent open() calls/disregards focus().
- **IE 8** opens a new window, honors focus().
- **Safari 5** opens a new window, and focuses on subsequent open() calls regardless if focus() is called or not.

Fiddle to test with: http://jsfiddle.net/jaraics/pEG3j/

Comment: If possible, please update your answer for iOs 9.3.2 - iphone6 (does not matter Chrome or Safari)  : opens a new tab, focuses on first open(), does not focus on subsequent open() calls/disregards focus().

Comment: @PhungD.An see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73690887/4420532)

Comment: How do I write a unit test for this in jest framework? Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 22):

You shouldn't need any logic for something like this. By default, specifying the second parameter for `window.open()` gives the window a "name", that the browser remembers. If you try to call `window.open()` with the same name (after it's already been opened), it doesn't open a new window...but you might still need to call `.focus()` on it. Try this:

```
var a = window.open(url, "name");
a.focus();
```

Those should be the only lines of code in your function, and you don't need the `loadingTableWnd` variable...

Comment: Giving a name indeed prevents opening a new window. But my problem is, that the user can navigate away(some functionality is controlled with hash(#) in the url) and I don't wish to reset that. I need the variable, because i must access the window from subsequent clicks on the link. Hence the need of a global variable.

Comment: @Ian Not true with latest version of windows OS like windows server 2012 R2

Answer (score 10):

If the window is already opened and if you want to focus on that window you can use

```
window.open('', 'NameOfTheOpenedWindow').focus();
```

Answer (score 3):

`window.focus()` is [widely supported](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_focus.asp) and seems to be working fine in both Internet Explorer and Firefox for me, the problem should be in your code. I've created a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pharaon/uJy5t/) for you to test.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle, but I can't get it to work with tabs(see my edit). Also I need to open a page on the current domain. (btw, your fiddle got removed for some reason)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not interested in retaining the state of a previously opened tab, you can do this:

```js
var loadingTableWnd;
function openOrSwitchToWindow(url) {
    if (loadingTableWnd != undefined) {
        loadingTableWnd.close();
    }
    loadingTableWnd = window.open(url,'myFrame');
}
```

Comment: one line:  wnd = wnd && wnd.close() || window.open(url, "wnd");

Answer (score 1):

It will always redirect to new tab with focus:

```
const redirectBlank = function(url) {
  return window.open(url, Date.now()).focus();
};
```