# iOS Safari - Give focus to window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, mobile-safari

I've got this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsFiddlePlayer/nv29wenu/)**, which has a simple `div` with a jQuery click handler:

```
<div class="testDiv" 
   data-target="http://www.stackoverflow.com" 
   data-open="false">
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var newWindow;
    $('.testDiv').on('click', function(e){
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        var open = $(this).data('open');

        if (!open){
            $(this).data('open','true');
            newWindow = window.open(target);
        }
        else {
            if (newWindow.closed){
                newWindow = window.open(target);
            }
            newWindow.focus();
        }
    });
})
```

The click handler on the `div` is designed to open a new window if it's not already open; if it's open, it gives that window focus. This works fine in Chrome on Win 7 x64 but on iOS 8.3's Safari (on an iPhone 6), once the window is open, clicking the `div` doesn't switch focus to the opened window. You have to close the window and open it again for it to gain focus.

Any solutions to this iOS Safari focus issue?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, tested on iOS (Tablet), MacOS (M1), Chrome:

```js
const link = 'http://...';
const target = 'NEW_WINDOW'

let win = window.open(link, target);

if (win && !win.closed) {
  win.close();
}

win = window.open(link, target);

if (win) {
  setTimeout(() => win.focus(), 100);
}
```