# window.focus() not working with onload event in chrome and opera.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open a new window onload of my html file. The new window is opening but after i am minimizing the window ,if i again load my html file then the new window is not getting focused.This issue is coming in chrome and opera.
attaching my html file.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="window.close(); MyWindow=window.open('url','MyWindow',width=420,height=470); window.location.href = 'url'; MyWindow.focus();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982593/open-link-in-new-window-or-focus-to-it-if-already-open       Please read this... I think it will help you