# Focus on already opened tab window issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show already opened tab window in chrome using javascript. it is working in firefox but not working in chrome and IE6,7,8. How can i modify this code to resolve that issue.
Js:

```
 self.close();
 var mypreWindow=window.open('test1.html','Start Page');  
 mypreWindow.focus();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982593/open-link-in-new-window-or-focus-to-it-if-already-open

Comment: The window name should have no blank spaces in it. [MDN window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Answer (score -2):

Unlike Firefox, the way Chrome handle windows and tabs are different(harder), sometimes you are not pointing to the right child(tab - Chrome tab) of a parent(window - Chrome), or not even to the right navigator... (yes chrome can be difficult like that...).
Could you show us more code so we can further assist? like how you get/start Chrome window, also, take a look at WinSpy++ and Spy++(Visual Studio), that might help you understand how chrome works.