# Attempting to open an existing tab with `window.open('', "foo").focus()` ("foo" is `window.name` of an existing tab) results in new about:blank tab

Tags: javascript, html

##### Reproduction:

1. Visit any website. Open browser console and execute `window.name="foo"`.
2. Open another tab of the same website and execute `window.open('', "foo").focus()`

**Result**: A new `about:blank` tab is opened instead of the tab that you named "foo". I've tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Is this expected behaviour? Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982593/open-link-in-new-window-or-focus-to-it-if-already-open) SO question/answer I thought it'd work.

##### Context

What I'm trying to achieve here is if a user clicks on a [Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification), I want to bring them to the page of the website that's relevant to that notification. But if they already have that page open (which is likely for this use case), then I want to just focus that tab.

Comment: The linked question/answer and the MDN documentation refer to using a name on windows that you (your code) opens.   ie an initial `window.open('', 'foo');` then a second/subsequent `window.open('', 'foo');` will reuse that window.  There's no mention/referencing a window that you didn't open with `window.open` - which includes the source window.  It's unclear if you open `foo1` then `foo2` if `foo2` can be reused from `foo1` - it would like create a new `foo2` with `foo1` as its parent.

Comment: Ah I see - thank you for your comment! So I guess it's not actually possible to achieve this "notification click opens relevant tab, or creates a new tab if it doesn't exist" behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As @freedomn-m said, this only works when you're trying to focus windows *which that same script created*. I.e. not arbitrary tabs that the user may have opened on their own.

My solution was to communicate between tabs via `BroadcastChannel`/`localStorage` so that the "correct" tab is the one which triggers the notification, and then the notification onclick simply calls `window.focus()`.

If no existing tab has "responded" after a few seconds, then I assume that there is not existing tab, and so I just trigger the notification in the "wrong" tab, and then call `window.open()` instead of `window.focus()`.