# How to use window.open() but still focus on original window on Chrome, Angular 14?

Tags: angular, focus, blur, window.open, angular14

I want to traverse the array and open its elements in the new Chrome Tab with their link. However, I don't want it to focus on the new Tab. Just focus on the original window.

Does anybody know any way to do it, please?

```
        for (let i = 0; i < this.linkSearchList.length; i++) {
            if (this.linkSearchList[i].note) {
                const newTab = window.open(this.linkSearchList[i].link, "_blank");
                if (newTab)
                    this.openingLinkSearchList.push(newTab);
            }
        }
```

I have tried to use newTab.blur() and window.focus() after opening new Chrome Tabs but it doesn't work

```
        for (let i = 0; i < this.linkSearchList.length; i++) {
            if (this.linkSearchList[i].note) {
                const newTab = window.open(this.linkSearchList[i].link, "_blank");
                if (newTab) {
                    this.openingLinkSearchList.push(newTab);
                    newTab.blur();
                }

            }
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
           window.focus();
        }, 100);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open link in new window or focus to it if already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982593/open-link-in-new-window-or-focus-to-it-if-already-open)

Comment: It's not my answer. I just want to stay at original window and open Tabs. (IT's work like when press CTRL and click on a tag in HTML)

Comment: Your attempts to use newTab.blur() and window.focus() are unlikely to work consistently because most browsers will override these attempts to force focus on the original window.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181464/i-need-to-open-a-new-window-in-the-background-with-javascript-and-make-sure-the
There only are workarounds that do not seem reliable. Browsers discourage this behaviour. Why is it a requirement for you?

Comment: Because these links (Dictionary Web's links) can't be used in Iframe, so I want to open all of them. And clients can do anything they want after that.
And `var popup = window.open(...); popup.blur(); window.focus();` doesn't work in my case.