# window.focus() not working for Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I'm trying to get the `window.focus()` function to work with no luck.

[**Take a look at this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/94KYp/)

```
var myWindow = window.open('','zzz','width=600,height=700');
    myWindow.document.write('test');
    myWindow.focus();​
```

If you click run after the jsfiddle page loads then the new window should get back focus. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [It's working for me in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/94KYp/5/).

Comment: @SheikhHeera Are you on Chrome 21?

Comment: @SheikhHeera I turned off all my extensions and it's still not working for me

Comment: Don't you see the window at the top and `Focused!` inside it ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera yes, the first time, but when I click run again, it doesn't refocus

Comment: But I can see the word `Focused` every time i focus it or run it again.

Comment: @SheikhHeera does it actually refocus, does it bring it to the top?

Comment: Yes, it's working and becomes the topmost window.

Comment: Solution discussed in other thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758608/window-focus-not-working-in-google-chrome

Comment: This thread is already discussed in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758608/window-focus-not-working-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It "works" for me in FF 15. Users can disable the ability of scripts to open and focus windows, check your settings. Oh, and the pop–up should get focus by default, so you shouldn't have to call `myWindow.focus()`.

Some minor points that probably having nothing to do with the issue but you may want to fix:

1. A valid document should be written to the new window, a title element and one block element are required, e.g. `document.write('<title></title><div></div>`, a DOCTYPE is highly recommended too
2. The input stream should be closed after you've finished writing, use `document.close()`

Comment: named popups will not focus after the initial opening.  so its still a good idea to call it.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome at least (dont have FF) just replace

```
myWindow.focus();
```

with

```
myWindow.blur();
setTimeout(myWindow.focus, 0);
```

EDIT: Realized I've got FF in a linux VM. The code is fine with the current Chrome and with FF12 under the newest Mint x64

Comment: Yeah it is. Works fine under: Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m (Win x64)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<script> 
var popupWin;
function open_popup(url) {
    if(typeof(popupWin) == "object" ) popupWin.close();

    popupWin =  window.open(url, 'PopupName', 'scrollbars=no,resizable=yes, width=600,height=800,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no'); 
    popupWin.focus();

 }
</script>
```