# window popup goes behind on mac machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos

This script works fine on windows machine and shows popup window on front.but in mac machine popup window goes behind of browser window.
i want to show popup window always on front in mac machine also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var win=null;

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#buttonid").live("click",function(){

                var alt = "http://www.testhost.com/test.php";
                var rel = "http://www.testhost.com/test2.php";               
                    var width= (window.innerWidth)-450;
                    var win = window.open(alt,"mywin","width=450,height="+window.innerHeight+",left="+width+", location=no, menubar=no, status=no, titlebar=no, scrollbars=no");

                    win.onload=function(){

                        window.location=rel;
                     }
                    if (window.focus) {
                       win.focus();
                     }
                     //setTimeout(win.focus(), 0);
                     return false;


        });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="buttonid">Click</button>
    </body>
```

Comment: what browser(s) are you using on Windows and Mac?

Comment: windows:Firefox,chrome and on mac:chrome,safari

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
if (window.focus) {
    win.blur();
    win.focus();
}
```

It's a fix for Chrome (webkit?). Here's the same solution from another question/answer:

[window.focus() not working in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758608/window-focus-not-working-in-google-chrome)

Comment: actually there is no browser issue..it works fine on development domain on mac but not works on live domain on mac