# Activate a window tab in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm developing web pages using only under google chrome browser.

For example, my page is opened in a tab called **MyTab**.

And some times, the user is viewing a page in an other tab **OtherTab**.

Now, I want to trigger an activation on **MyTab**.

Then I tried:

```
<script>
// MyTab
setTimeout(function() {
    alert('activated');
}, 5000);
</script>
```

This do works, the **MyTab** page pops to the front.

---

#### Problem:

But I don't want to produce an `alert();`

Then I tried to call `window.focus()`:

```
<script>
// MyTab
setTimeout(function() {
    window.focus();
}, 5000);
</script>
```

But with no luck. It seems the `window.focus()` method do not work.

Then I tried to find the problem: [window.focus() not working in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758608/window-focus-not-working-in-google-chrome)

But it don't quite points out to a solution for me.

---

So, is there any way to pop the window tab to the front, with out using `alert()`?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704206/how-to-change-browser-focus-from-one-tab-to-another

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know opening new tab is only way to achieve that.

```
$.get(location.href, function(){window.open(location.href)}, 'html');
setTimeout(function(){
  window.opener = window;
  window.close();
},1000);
```

open new tab of same adrress. and close the old one.

Comment: Does it mean the old page must be reloaded?

Comment: I mean duplicating(opening a new tab which has same location) the page is only way to force activate a tab in chrome.and yes it's almost same meaning it has to be reloaded(fresh loaded).