# Multiple browser window application using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

I have 5 rows of different usernames in a grid( search pae ).
When I click on the first name it will be opened in a new window (user Info). Like that 5 different windows can be opened.

In search page ,I have the reference of these windows. When I hover on the reference from the search screen, particular window has to be focused and when I close the user info window manually this reference from the search screen has to be removed.

Please tell me solutions or links to implement this concepts..

Comment: so you are trying to develop a multiple page application in a single page framework and aren't sure how to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working code. It is for demo purpose to show how you can work with multiple windows. Instead hovering, it needs you to click on a search link to create or set focus to the new window. Also it demonstrates the action of the window-closing by removing the corresponding search result itself.

What we are going to do is to have an array of references to the the opened windows in our controller. You should create your DOM search results with appropriate attributes and populate this array as you insert them to the document.

Here is what the array should look like after loading your search results.

```
$scope.winRef = [   {id: 'user1', w: 0, show: true}, 
                    {id: 'user2', w: 0, show: true}, 
                    {id: 'user3', w: 0, show: true}];
```

The array can record the window handler (w), user id and the show status. The show status is bound to the DOM element through `ng-show`.

Here is the DOM search results:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="openWindow(0)" id="user1" ng-show="winRef[0].show">User1</a> <br>
<a href="#" ng-click="openWindow(1)" id="user1" ng-show="winRef[1].show">User2</a> <br>
<a href="#" ng-click="openWindow(2)" id="user1" ng-show="winRef[2].show">User3</a> <br>
```

You cans see that when the user clicks on a link it calls the `openWindow()` function. This function checks through the array if a window is already opened for this user. It opens one if yes or set the focus through `w` if not. Here is your `openWindow` function:

```
$scope.openWindow = function(userIdx) {

       if ($scope.winRef[userIdx].w === 0) {
          $scope.winRef[userIdx].w = $window.open();


          //Write something in the new page                                                       
          $scope.winRef[userIdx].w.document.write($scope.winRef[userIdx].id);


          //Set the unload event for your new window. 
          $scope.winRef[userIdx].w.onbeforeunload = function() {

               //Note that we create a closure here. Also note the 
               //applicaiton of the $apply here. 
               $scope.$apply($scope.winRef[userIdx].show = false);                           
           };                      
      }            
      else
         $scope.winRef[userIdx].w.focus();
};
```

And finally you can see that I have bound the `unbeforeunload` event of the new window with a function. This function sets the `show` property of the appropriate element `false` to hide your DOM search result. Here is the function:

```
$scope.removeSearchResult = function(userIdx) {
    $scope.winRef[userIdx].show = false;
};
```

This code works perfectly if you put them inside a controller. Also read my comments on the code to note few things I have highlighted.

This is a rough idea of how you should solve your problem. This can extend greatly by loading an html file to the new window and making the controller interact with it through `onload` event of the new window. Please play with it and learn your methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot Charlie.. Sorry for the delayed response.. And $scope.winref[userIdx].w.focus() is not working.. Please help me on this.

Comment: What is your browser?

Comment: IE and I checked in Firefox too.. Its not working.. When I click the same name it has to be focused the particular window right.. It's not working

Comment: I tested this code in Chrome and verified it was working before posting here. This is the mock program I did to answer your question. Anyway I have provided you with a method through which you can accomplish your task. Please learn from it and apply it in to your project. Here is a link for focus related problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758608/window-focus-not-working-in-google-chrome