# Highlight the minimize the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have create a custom call messenger which is working perfectly fine without any issue.

I need a suggestion for when i minimize the messenger browser window and that time if any call comes in i want to show some kind of indication in terms of pop out that window or highlight.

I have tried `window.focus` which work if the window is not focus but when it's minimized it's not working.

Is there any other way which way i can show any indication to particular window.

Comment: Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: currently working on chrome but its not working on any browser.

Comment: I made up this experiment in codepen: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/5c2fc4eaab757284012801ce27d4a8e2 I works in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 on Windows. I can focus on all the new windows from the source window. But, and that might be the case with your issue: if you reload the originating window, all the references to your new window will be lost, and it won't work anymore.

Comment: Yes you are right because i am connecting to call server new window will disconnect  .

Comment: maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21024022/476951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at javascript [Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) for that

Additionaly you could change the [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title) or the favicon to indicate that this tab has some notifications like YouTube does it for example with the counter of notifications in the title

Answer (score 0):

The open call returns a reference to the new window. It can be used to manipulate it’s properties, change location and even more.

In this example, we generate popup content from JavaScript:

```
let newWin = window.open("about:blank", "hello", "width=200,height=200");
newWin.document.write("Hello, world!");
```

And here we modify the contents after loading:

```
let newWindow = open('/', 'example', 'width=300,height=300')
newWindow.focus();
alert(newWin.location.href); // (*) about:blank, loading hasn't started yet
newWindow.onload = function() {
  let html = `<div style="font-size:30px">Welcome!</div>`;
  newWindow.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
};
```

Please note: immediately after window.open, the new window isn’t loaded yet. That’s demonstrated by alert in line (*). So we wait for onload to modify it. We could also use DOMContentLoaded handler for newWin.document.